# Transition between extremal and non-extremal black hole states

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, hawking-radiation

Extremal black holes are at zero temperature, hence they do not radiate.

My question is twofold:

1. **Is extremality of micro black holes a stable property?** Electric charge is quickly emitted from sub-atomic black holes due to Schwinger pair production, what about angular momentum? Does a black hole loses its extremality quickly or slowly (compared to its evaporation time)?
2. **Can a black hole extremality state be changed by external sources?** Can we add matter and angular momentum appropriately to a Schwarzschild black hole in order for it to become extremal or nearly-extremal? Can we do the inverse process?

Comment: 1) Extremal black holes are always unstable (in standard GR at least, I can't speak for string theory etc) e.g. see https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.6598.  
2) Yes, a black hole can gain/lose charge/angular-momentum due to in-falling matter. In theory it'd be possible to add charged matter to make a Kerr black hole become extremal, and matter of the opposite charge to do the inverse, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of supersymmetric extremal black holes:

1.- Extremality is stable under the change of black hole radius (as far as the radii is not too close to the Planck length).

2.- An extremal black hole can be made non-extremal by probing it with objects such that the (probes + extremal black hole) bound state breaks some supersymmetries. An example of this could be the classical $D1$-$D5$ system with $D$(-1)-instantons or dyonic states in type IIB superstring theory, or studying some  1/16 black hole solution in Maldacena's $AdS_{5}$ $ \times $ $\mathcal{S}^5$ on a non-trivial D(-1) instanton background.

Recall that an interesting open problem is to discover if 1/16-BPS supergravity black hole solutions exist in full string theory or if they are "destroyed by stringy corrections" (Reference: [Xi Yin, Strings 2013](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QbyPI1MFbGA))). If they don't really exist, you may be able to produce non-extremal black holes by perturbing extremal ones with available supersymmetric proves like D-instantons (instanton solutions for the near-horizon geometry of a stack of $D3$ branes) and breaking some supersymmetries until the 1/16 (or fewer) unstable situation is reached.

---

You can also read the most upvoted answer to the question [Why Do Extremal Black Holes Not Radiate?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/356955/why-do-extremal-black-holes-not-radiate/357758). The answer beautifully explains how galactic black holes of the Kerr-type "regulate themselves" by purely "mundane" astrophysical mechanisms in order to keep the angular momentum to mass squared ratio less than one - that is, non-extremal.

**Edit:** By "probing it with objects" I meant to embed a particular black hole solution in a non trivial background with that particular object. In the [famous $D5$-$D1$ system for type IIB strings compactfied on $\mathcal{T}^4$ $ \times $ $\mathcal{S}^1$](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0002184) that means studying the black hole solution on a non-trivial $D$(-1) instanton background (this was done [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1010.3373) in a T-duality related case).

A nice example of how an extremal $D3$- black branes are made non-extremal is discussed at section 3.2 in [these lecture notes](https://www.ipht.fr/Docspht/articles/t12/003/public/2012_Bena+ElShowk_by_Vercnocke_All_Lectures.pdf), ([alternative link](https://inspirehep.net/literature/1262861)). Another set of nice results that analyze non-extremal 4D black hole solutions, with $\mathcal{N}=2,4,8$,by embedding them on non-trivial backgrounds is [Non-supersymmetric Black Holes and Topological Strings](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0703214). Both cases are examples of extremal black hole solutions "being probed": being made non-extremal by coupling them to non trivial backgrounds, or adding anti-branes.

Comment: This answer is hard to understand. What does *"proving it with objects"* mean?

Comment: Sorry, it was not my intention to confuse you. I added an edit to my answer in order to try to satisfy your observation.